# Как в регулярном выражение выбрать определенный вариант?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Здравствуйте, как выбрать последний вариант в регулярных выражениях? Другими словами, когда по заданными параметрами попадаются несколько вариантов, как выбрать конкретный? Например:

**текст:**
 цена 200, цена 400, цена 600.   '

**регулярное выражение:**
цена ([0-9]+)

Как выбрать определенный вариант средствами регулярных выражений? ( например последний или второй)

Comment: [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) может вернуть массив `matches` всех вхождений. Берите последнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня так сработало:

```
$text = "цена 200, цена 400, цена 600.";
preg_match_all("/цена ([0-9]+)/", $text, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$lastprice = end($matches[1]);
```

http://ideone.com/xQYVdU

---

Если нужно именно `preg_match`, должен пойти такой вариант:

```
$text = "цена 200, цена 400, цена 600.";
preg_match("/цена ([0-9]+)(?!.*цена [0-9]+)/", $text, $matches);
```

http://ideone.com/oVOSvJ

Comment: А чисто регулярным выражением нельзя?)

Comment: @Node_pro: Вам ехать или шашечки? Наверняка как-то можно, но зачем?

Comment: Дело в том, что как это пошло не звучит но регулярка должна хранится в базе данных. А функция для выполнение регулярного выражения должна быть одна. Не спрашивайте зачем, так хочет заказчик ;-)

Comment: @VladD: Спасибо, надеюсь на Вашу помощь

Comment: @Node_pro: а так: <http://ideone.com/oVOSvJ>?

Comment: `<?php
$text = "цена 200, цена 400, цена 600.";
preg_match("/цена ([0-9]+)(?!.*цена [0-9]+)/", $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
 
?>` такой вариант подойдет, спасибо. А не могли Вы рассказать, что вы сделали. И еще такой вопрос не в тему. В чем разница когда начинается регулярное выражение со / или #?

Comment: @Node_pro: 1) Я сделал отрицательный lookahead: добавил проверку, что после вхождения других вхождений нет.

2) В принципе, ни в чём. Просто если в само выражение входит `/`, с `/regex/` его приходится экранировать, чтобы его не regex engine не приняла за конец выражения. А с `#` или любым другим знаком — нет.